# How to compare and return excel sheet names to a dict of list

Tags: python

I have an excel file with multiple sheets. I want to get only the sheet that is present in yaml file shown as below:

```
config = {'sheet': ['Designs']}
```

After edits(with regards to comments):

```
if config is not None:
    ws = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name=config['sheet'])
```

Output of ws looks like below:

```
{'Designs':         id       text discipline
 0  des-345  Wonderful         md
 1  tni-982     Thanks         hw
 2  xpn-675      Enjoy         sw}
```

How to convert this to a dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why your using read_excel first, read the sheet you want with pd.read_excel

```
if config['sheet']:
    ws = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name=config['sheet'])
```

if ws is a dict then

`ws = pd.DataFrame(ws['design'])`

Comment: This helps. But the output of ws id dict. How can I get it as dataframe

Comment: try `pd.DataFrame(ws)` or` pd.concat(ws)` or `pd.concat(pd.DataFrame(ws)`

Comment: ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index - I get this error if I try to change to dataframe

Comment: can you post what `ws` looks like